# Ubuntu 22.04 Save as dialog box not showing

Tags: 22.04, freeze, pdf, gedit

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my old macbok pro (mid 2010). The issue is I cant save changes made to any file, whether its a text document or pdf downloaded from the internet. On editing a new file, Text editor will freeze and not respond whenever I hit the save button. Similarly, Document viewer will freeze if I highlight some text and try to save the same pdf.

I tried
`sudo gedit *filename*`
and it works for creating and saving a new text file. I am seeking a more gui oriented solution as I will be highlighting pdfs and working on other text editors.

Major Edit

I just realized that program do not freeze but the save as dialog box is not showing on the screen. I can see its there and when I randomly hit enter, the files save with the name in the dialog box. Just changed the title of the question to reflect this edit.

Will appreciate of any help to bring the save as dialog box to current view or any tip that can enable me to interact with save as dialog box so that I can save the files at correct location and name. I also tried the following with no success

`sudo apt install xdg-desktop-portal xdg-desktop-portal-gtk`

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. On a fresh 22.04 TLS install, the File Save dialogue box stopped showing up.

The good news is that `sudo apt install xdg-desktop-portal xdg-desktop-portal-gtk` worked for me.

For some reason the system settings had also disappeared. I got them back by installing gnome-control-center.

Answer (score 0):

None of file dialog boxes were showing up. This worked for me too:

```
sudo apt install xdg-desktop-portal xdg-desktop-portal-gtk
```